# Android java app breaks if I attempt to initialise item in object array

Tags: java, android, arrays, object

I have declared an array of objects in the main activity of my Android app. I initialise the array (so far no problem) but as soon as I attempt to initialise one of the elements, my app breaks.

Here is the code from the main activity:

```
private cClubMemberDetails[] PlayerNames;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    PlayerNames = new cClubMemberDetails[4];
    PlayerNames[0] = new cClubMemberDetails();
```

It's that last line, setting PlayerNames[0], that causes the problem. If I comment out this line, the app works. If I leave it in, the app crashes before showing its opening screen (and long before I make any further use of the PlayerNames array). It's clearly something specific to the cClubMemberDetails class. I can initialise arrays of other types of object no problem. But the class is as simple as can be. Here it is in its entirety:

```
package uk.org.writerman.scoresheet;

/**
 * Created by keith on 18/07/2016.
 */
public class cClubMemberDetails {
    private int m_ClubNumber;
    private String m_MemberName;
    private int m_EBUNumber;

    public cClubMemberDetails() {
        m_ClubNumber = -1;
        m_MemberName = "";
        m_EBUNumber = 0;
    }
    public cClubMemberDetails(int ClubNumber, String MemberName, int EBUNo) {
       setTo(ClubNumber, MemberName, EBUNo);
    }

    public int getClubNumber()      {   return m_ClubNumber;    }
    public String getMemberName()   {   return m_MemberName;    }
    public int getEBUNumber()       {   return m_EBUNumber;     }

//    public void setClubNumber(int ClubNumber)       {   m_ClubNumber = ClubNumber;  }
//    public void setMemberName(String MemberName)    {   m_MemberName = MemberName;  }


    public void setTo(int ClubNumber, String MemberName, int EBUNumber) {
        m_ClubNumber = ClubNumber;
        m_MemberName = MemberName;
        m_EBUNumber = EBUNumber;
    }

    public boolean collatesAfter(cClubMemberDetails Another) {
        return (m_MemberName.compareToIgnoreCase(Another.getMemberName()) > 0);
    }
    public boolean collatesBefore(cClubMemberDetails Another) {
        return (m_MemberName.compareToIgnoreCase(Another.getMemberName()) < 0);
    }

}
```

Any suggestions what could be going on? I'm at my wits' end (but maybe my wits don't amount to much)
Keith

Comment: If your app crashes, there will generally be some helpful information in logcat, such as a stack trace.

Comment: @ceph3us The OP appears to be instantiating the array correctly?  Anyway reading stack traces is not hard, I'm sure he can do it!

Comment: @TavianBarnes correctly yeah?  what is on left side ?

Comment: @ceph3us A field named `PlayerNames`, whose declaration is visible in the code

Comment: @ceph3us there's no need to be rude. If OP doesn't know how to read the stack trace he will ask for help. That's the point of this website, to help people learn the technologies they work with

Comment: I ran this exact code and didn't have any issues. Maybe try cleaning and rebuilding your project (Android Studio Build -> Clean Build -> Rebuild, who knows. Otherwise as @TavianBarnes said there should be stacktrace if you open Android Monitor. Seems like it could also be crashing after that line if you access something around that assignment in your `onCreate()`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm new to Android programming (although 30+ years as a Windows programmer) so I've only just discovered LogCat. I will see if this helps. I should have mentioned that the actual crash comes much later (about 2 seconds later) with an "app has stopped" message. I shall try again and see if LogCat throws any light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. Logcat revealed the problem and it was nothing to do with the code as posted. The program crashed in onSaveInstanceState when writing the contents of my array to the output bundle. Of course, no entries in the array = no opportunity for onSaveInstanceState to go wrong saving them. Doh!

Thanks again. I am slowly getting the hang of this Android stuff and the dev environment.

Keith